# get array value from bluetooth low energy fff2 characteristic on Java

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need to get value from fff2 characteristic.
Its characteristic only return 01 or 00

How to get its value?
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Gvu8.jpg) is example value that I want.

```
public boolean readCharacteristic(){

    //check mBluetoothGatt is available
    if (bluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "lost connection");
        return false;
    }
    BluetoothGattService Service = bluetoothGatt.getService(UUID.fromString("0000fff0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
    if (Service == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "service not found!");
        return false;
    }
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic charac = Service
            .getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("0000fff2-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));


    if (charac == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "char not found!");
        return false;
    }
        final byte[] data = charac.getValue(); // return null
        String s2 = new String(data);

        Log.i("READ", s2);
        boolean status = true;

        return status;

}
```

thanks..

Comment: please post u r code.

Comment: that's my code @7383

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {

        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
        }
    }
```

Convert the byte array to Hex format if required.
Hope this is helpful.